# React project script linter error Missing "key" prop for element in iterator

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am calling from parent component

```
import { ChildClass } from '../../path/to/child'
<ChildClass
            appData={appData}
            deviceOS={deviceOS}
            mobileFlag={mobileFlag}
/>
```

and the child component

```
const ChildClass = props => {
           const appData = props.appData,
           mobileFlag = props.mobileFlag,
           deviceOS = props.deviceOS
           return(<div>Hello etc.</div>)}
export { ChildClass }
```

But I am getting error in linter -

```
error    Missing "key" prop for element in iterator                                              react/jsx-key
```

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Can you include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, and the full error message as it likely tells you the exact line number where the issue is and in many cases, offers the solution to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're rendering your ChildClass component inside an iteration. For that, React uses a `key` component to identify each instance of `ChildClass` and have control over renders/re-renders of each component.

```
<ChildClass
  key={uniqueId}
  appData={appData}
  deviceOS={deviceOS}
  mobileFlag={mobileFlag}
/>
```

Key has to be unique, so usually you use an unique property available from your Parent class (could be an event id, username, etc). You can also use `index` property from an interator function, or libraries like uuidv4.

```
const childItems = childs.map((child, index) =>
  <ChildClass
    key={index}
    appData={appData}
    deviceOS={deviceOS}
    mobileFlag={mobileFlag}
  />
)
```

Although, consider this note from the React documentation:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state

[Related article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: If you are going to mention using the array index as a react key then please at least also mention why you normally wouldn't want to. From the List & Keys react docs: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318 There is a pretty specific circumstance where the array index is acceptable as react key.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added it as a note. You're right, it helps to understand why would this be detrimental to the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you display a list of elements in an iteration, you should add a key prop with unique identify values that helps React keep track of changes. Probably your linter is configure to fail if you miss that.

[React lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)